# How to use a conditional within a Ruby expect script

Tags: ruby, expect

I'm playing with expect in Ruby but I'm a little lost as to how I can branch my code based on the behavior of a device I am logging into.  How could I do say `foo.run` if I get the correct prompt below `>` but run `foo.fail` if I do not?  Even further, how can I evaluate all of the text that comes back between entering the password and receiving the `>` prompt?  Is there a way to look at all text that the device prints somehow?

```
   def device_test(password)
      $expect_verbose = true
      PTY.spawn("ssh my-router") do |reader, writer, pid|
         reader.expect("password:")
         writer.puts(password)
         reader.expect(">")        
         puts "logged in"
         sleep(15)
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the expect method can only look for a single pattern (unlike the Tcl expect library where you can look for multiple patterns simultaneously).

It looks like you'll have to pass a "timeout" parameter and check the return value:

```
if reader.expect(">", 2)
  puts "foo.run"
else
  # did not see ">" within 2 seconds
  puts "foo.fail
end
```